# Have to wait for applications to load in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10

When I press on an app in the dock panel, I have to wait for 50< seconds for it to open.

Is there a way to make apps open faster?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has at least 4GB RAM, you can install an application called *preload* from the default Ubuntu repositories with `sudo apt install preload`.

Preload monitors applications that users run, and by analyzing this data, predicts what applications users might run, and fetches those binaries and their dependencies into memory for faster startup times.

The key words here are "into memory". If your computer doesn't have enough RAM memory to support applications caching, then preload will cause your system to have generally degraded performance, especially immediately after booting the system. On the other hand, if your computer has 16GB RAM or more then installing preload won't make any noticeable improvement in application launch times.

I have preload installed on my Ubuntu, and I have also noticed that some applications that use a lot of system resources start up faster the second time I launch them after booting. Both Firefox and Chromium start up right away though.